# Change %ComSpec% from cmd.exe to bash.exe

Tags: windows, bash, cmd, console

Is it safe to change %ComSpec% from `cmd.exe` to `bash.exe`(installed with `git-for-windows`)?

Are there any pitfalls while changing this enviroment variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine that a lot of existing apps and scripts assume that `%ComSpec%` points to an interpreter that is compatible with cmd.exe/command.com. And by compatible I mean the command line arguments it supports, the internal commands it supports and the way it parses and executes batch files.

Make your own variable if you need one for your own scripts or just make sure the path to bash.exe is in `%Path%`. Expecting other applications to cope with Bash is not going to work out well in the long run...